# Exercise measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$  be Lebesgue integrable such that $f(0)=0$  and $f$ derivable at  $0$.

Let $g:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ be defined as $$g=\begin{cases}
\frac{f(x)}{x} &\text{ if }x\neq 0, \\
0 &\text{ if }x=0.
\end{cases} $$
I need hint to proof that $g$ integrable with respect to Lebesgue measure.

Comment: Can you show $g$ is bounded near $0$ from the condition that $f'(0)$ exists? Note that you can split $\int|g|$ as $$\int_\Bbb R|g|=\int_{|x|\leq 1}|g|+\int_{|x|>1}|g|.$$

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $f'(0)\neq 0$ (I let you manage when $f'(0)=0$). Since $f$ is derivable at $0$, there is $\delta >0$ s.t. $$|g(x)|\leq 2|f'(0)|,$$
when $|x|<\delta $. So $$\int_{|x|<\delta }|g|\leq 2\delta |f'(0)|<\infty .$$
Now, $$\int_{|x|>\delta }|g|\leq \frac{1}{\delta }\int_{\mathbb R}|f|<\infty .$$

Therefore $$\int_{\mathbb R}|g|=\int_{|x|<\delta }|g|+\int_{|x|>\delta }|g|<\infty .$$

Comment: Since $f$ derivable at $0$ ,so threre is  $\delta>0 $,  $$ |g(x)| \leq \sup_{|x|<\delta }|f'(x)| $$
why you used  $2|f'(0)|$ , and
How did you get the second inequality ?

Comment: @chettahoussama: I applied $\varepsilon ,\delta $ definition with $\varepsilon =|f'(0)|$.